# use -source 8 or higher to enable lambda expressions

Tags: java, maven, lambda, java-8

I'm facing a build error when I try to run a Maven build. I created a simple Java project which includes lambda functions, due to this I'm getting

```
[ERROR] (...) lambda expressions are not supported in -source 1.5
[ERROR]   (use -source 8 or higher to enable lambda expressions)
```

My Java version is 1.8.0_172, my Maven version is 3.6.0.

Comment: maven compiler plugin settings...

Comment: target and source must both be set to `8`

Comment: you can also provide the respective properties [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59733198/1529709), without editing a POM

Answer (score 12):

Add to your pom.xml

```
<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <maven.compiler.source>${java.version}</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>${java.version}</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
```

Answer (score 3):

use maven compiler 1.8 or greater to enable lambda expressions in your code. Add the compiler as properties in your pom.xml